# Why does a span affect the vertical positioning of a sibling span

Tags: html, css, alignment

In the following HTML page, I have a div, which contains two spans (`span1` and `span2`), the second of which contains a sub-span, `span2a`. The `span1` contains text, as does the `span2a`.  With this setup, the vertical alignment of the text differs, and I can't work out why.

To complicate matters, there are style attributes on the `span2` and `span2a`. I have no control over these, as they're injected at runtime by the jQuery cycle plugin.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title> 
    <style type="text/css">
        body {margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: arial; color: black;}
        .container { height: 30px; text-align: left; padding: 8px 15px 0 15px; background-color: #fee; border: 1px solid red;}
        .ticker { font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 4px; float: left;}
        .ticker > span:first-child { background-color: #bfb; }
        .tickerscroll { display: inline-block; background-color: #bbf; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="ticker">
            <span class="span1">LABEL: </span>
            <span class="span2 tickerscroll" style="position: relative; width: 480px; height: 15px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; ">
                <span class="span2a" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 3; left: 0px; ">The value (in a sub-span; note that Label is lower then this text)</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="ticker">
            <span class="span1">LABEL: </span>
            <span class="span2 tickerscroll" style="position: relative; width: 480px; height: 15px; ">
                &nbsp;<span class="span2a" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; ">The value (this time, I've added a &amp;nbsp; outside this inner span)</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="ticker">
            <span class="span1">LABEL: </span>
            <span class="span2 tickerscroll" style="position: relative; width: 480px; height: 15px; ">
                The value (this time, the inner span span2a is not present at all)
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see from my code, I've added two variants which "fix" the issue:

1. Add some text (any text, in my case I've added a non-breaking space) inside the `span2` outside of `span2a`.
2. Remove the sub-span altogether, and have the text just inside the second top-level span. However, this isn't an option for me, as the presence of span2a is required to make the jQuery cycling work.

Is there a way to make the two pieces of text aligned the same without having to artifically throw a &nbsp; into `span2`?  The solution cannot change the style attributes of any of the span elements, but can add CSS classes if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vertical align is different because `span` tags are naturally inline elements, in your case you are modifying that behavior on your `span2` class by creating a block-level element with your `overflow:hidden` property. You can fix it by defining your `span1` class also as a block-level element with `display:inline-block` and simply aligning it to the top with the `vertical-align:top` property or floating it to the left:

```
.span1 {
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie 7 fix */
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Or

```
.span1 {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I tried so many things, I'm amazed I hadn't tried this already. Interestingly, your solution seems to work without the IE7 fix, at least in IE8 running in IE7 compatibility mode ... .

Comment: This has been the cause of many problems for me. I'm so happy to have finally found a solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    .ticker span {vertical-align:top}
```

To answer you question: Span 2 is empty, therefore there is nothing to align with span 1.
Span 2 is the containing block of the absolutely positioned span 2a, and this 2a starts at top:0; left:0 of span 2, thus the misalignment.

the second case: if span 2 is not empty, it will be baseline-aligned with span 1, and the a.p. span 2a is aligned as expected.

case 3 is just the same as case 2.

Comment: +1 for a solution which works. However, I'm giving the accepted answer to @Andres Ilich who provided a working solution first. Thanks though!

Comment: Also, you've given a great explanation of baseline alignment, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this :

Have all of those 3 span have the same line-height and same vertical align

Example :

```
.span1, .span2, .span2a
{
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt @Zwik. However, this actually reverses the problem, and the labels are now higher than the values! vertical-align: top did the trick, so I'm guessing that the line height directive is being ignored?

Comment: Actually no, it is taken in consideration. The code I posted was only an example to show what I had explained ;). In the end if you use vert align top, you will have some unused space under your text unless the font-size is big enough.